# mysqldump not working

Tags: mysql

When I run the mysqldump command to restore a database, I see a bunch of lines followed by a status saying "Dump completed". But when I check, there is no change in the database. Here is the code for the dump:

```
mysqldump -uroot -p mydb < /home/gaurav/mydb.sql
```

And here is the output I see when I run the mysqldump command:

```
-- MySQL dump 10.11
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: drupal7_new
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version       5.0.77

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0                                              */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

-- Dump completed on 2011-11-10  9:48:18
```

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to do this

```
mysql -uroot -p mydb < /home/gaurav/mydb.sql
```

Comment: why isn't there a space between `-u` and `root`?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that your mysqldump file is to big and over the limit set in php.ini config file, but mysqldump will not tell you that.

First, locate the php.ini file, this command is for linux.

```
$ sudo php --ini
```

This command will give you a list of paths, look for one where php.ini is.

Open is with your editor and look for a setting called:

```
upload_max_filesize = 2M
```

change the setting to 4M or a size bigger than than your dumpfile.

This will solve your problem.